# Is there something like test_requires in Elixir's mix?

Tags: elixir

In Python's setup.py we can specify dependencies that should be downloaded and installed as eggs by specifying under `test_requires` the requirements. In Elixir's mix how do I specify dependencies that I want to only use for tests ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dependencies in Mix are placed inside a private function called `deps`, it is not a rule, it is only the default value of the `deps` entry in the `project` "section", see below:

```
def project do
 [ app: :teste,
    version: "0.0.1",
    elixir: "~> 0.12.5-dev",
    deps: deps ] # It's here!
end
```

You can declare a `deps` function for test's dependencies and set the `deps` entry above to `deps(Mix.env)`. This is a way to tell Mix to call `deps` with a param that come from `MIX_ENV` enviroment variable.

This snippet could help you to understand better, let me show you:

```
...

def project do
  [ app: :teste,
    version: "0.0.1",
    elixir: "~> 0.12.5-dev",
    deps: deps(Mix.env) ] # This is important :)
end

...

defp deps(:prod) do
   [ { :a_production_ready_dependency, github: "xpto/cool_project" } ] 
end

defp deps(:test) do
   [ { :some_project, github: "some_project/other" } ]
end

defp deps(_) do
   deps(:prod) ++ [ { :a_devel_dependency, github: "xpto_dev/cool_project_dev" } ]
end

...
```

Notice that you can still have a default dependency list with `defp deps(_)`, in the case that none of the functions above was pattern-matched. ;)

Then you should call `mix` as:

```
MIX_ENV=test mix deps.get
```

This could not be the best way to do that, but I'm using it often and sounds simple to me.

Comment: This is the correct answer up to v0.12. On v0.13, we support the `:only` option, so you can do: `{:some_project, github: "...", only: [:dev, :test]}`.

Comment: Thanks for point it! I didn't switch to v0.13 yet and didn't notice that. Thanks.